# Rewrite another module block issue in Magento1

Tags: module, magento-1, blocks

This is my XML from my module X:

```
<global>
        <blocks>
.......
            <namespaceY_moduleY>
                <rewrite>
                    <subscription_grid>NamespaceX_ModuleX_Block_Adminhtml_Subscription_Grid</subscription_grid>
                </rewrite>
            </namespaceY_moduleY>
        </blocks>
...
```

In my module X I want to rewrite a block from module Y . What am i doing wrong? I put a syntax error in my NamespaceX_ModuleX_Block_Adminhtml_Subscription_Grid and i don't get it. This is my block from module X:

```
class NamespaceX_ModuleX_Block_Adminhtml_Subscription_Grid extends NamespaceY_ModuleY_Block_Adminhtml_Subscription_Grid
{
asdasdsa
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Magento rewrite a class using it ***object prefix not using*** `[NameSpace]_[moduleName]`

```
<namespaceY_moduleY>  <!-- it is wrong -, it should be block class prefix-->
    <rewrite>
        <subscription_grid>NamespaceX_ModuleX_Block_Adminhtml_Subscription_Grid</subscription_grid>
    </rewrite>
</namespaceY_moduleY>
```

In your question,You have use   `<namespaceY_moduleY>`.but it should be ***block  class prefix/identifier***  which in define at config.xml of  your module.

If you have open the NamespaceY_ModuleY's config then on it's under 
`<global><blocks>....</block></global>` .you will found the block class **prefix of identifier of block of that module**

```
<global>
        .... 
        <blocks>
            <[This_Is_YOUR_IDENTIFIER]> <!--- This tag is called idenfier -->
                    <class>namespaceY_moduleY_Block</subscription_grid>
                </rewrite>
            </[This_Is_YOUR_IDENTIFIER]> 
        </blocks>
 .......
```

---

So, you should use `[This_Is_YOUR_IDENTIFIER] instead` of    `namespaceY_moduleY` at **NamespaceX_ModuleX**  module **`config.xml`**

=======

---

### What is Prefix of block of a module

Suppose, for those case,i have taken the example of Mage_Catalog.
Let check the config.xml of this module.

And `catalog` is block class **prefix/identifier** for **Mage_Catalog** module

Please see the below.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Mage_Catalog>
            .....
        </Mage_Catalog>
    </modules>
    .......
    <global>
        <models>
            <catalog> <!-- this catalog is model prefix of module Mage_Catalog module -->
                <class>Mage_Catalog_Model</class>
            </catalog>
        </models>
        <blocks>
            <catalog>  <!-- this catalog is block prefix of module Mage_Catalog module -->
                <class>Mage_Catalog_Block</class>
            </catalog>
        </blocks>
</config>
```